# Latex entry glossary

Tags: spacing, glossaries

I've several entries in my glossary, the problem is that there is no horizontal space between the words. These are some examples how I wrote them down. Once inserted in the general text: `\gls{shopfloor}` the words are written correctly as shop floor. With a space between the word shop and floor. However in the glossary itself the words are written as:

*shopfloor* The part of a workshop or factory where production as distinct from administrative work is carried out

I want it to look like this, with the space between shop floor

*shop floor* The part of a workshop or factory where production as distinct from administrative work is carried out

```
 \newglossaryentry{shopfloor}
{
    name=shop floor,
    description={The part of a workshop or factory where production as distinct from administrative work is carried out}
}
```

Already tried to write `name=shop\space floor` but that does not work.

Comment: Question can be closed

Comment: You can accept the provided answer if it solved your problem. I am not sure what you mean by "question can be closed".

Comment: @Dr. Manuel Kuehner There is not a "correct answer". With some guidance, the OP solved the problem himself. (a line of his code not shown in the question)

Comment: Thanks @Simon for the reply. I now see that the OP used math mode which removed the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple code produces the result you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

 \newglossaryentry{shopfloor}
{
    name=shop floor,
    description={The part of a workshop or factory where production as distinct from administrative work is carried out}
}

\begin{document}

    \gls{shopfloor}
        
    \printglossaries        

\end{document}
```

[image: a]

Comment: Thanks, however, I still got another results

Comment: @mr_laut Try my code alone. pdflatex file.tex + Makeglossaries file + pdflatex. file.tex

Comment: i'll try and find out which package is the problem. Atleast your code works. I've added my packages and its the same again. So, I'll dive into this yself

Comment: I found the problem
\renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\leftmargin$#1$}

This line of code was the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

 \newglossaryentry{shopfloor}
{
    name=shop floor,
    description={The part of a workshop or factory where production as distinct from administrative work is carried out}
}

\begin{document}

    \gls{shopfloor}
        
    \printglossaries        

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: The output you show is not from the above code. When I run it the result is corrrect. Since this not an answer, please put the code and the output in your question.